# Uncaught GATEWAY_DISCONNECTED | Connection to Twilio's servers was lost

Tags: video, twilio, twilio-api

I downloaded the starter kit for programmable video. The standalone code works but when I integrated the code with my react app, it gives me this strange error

```
Uncaught GATEWAY_DISCONNECTED | Connection to Twilio's servers was lost
```

I have left all the quickstart.js as it is except that when my video component mounts, i am calling an init function which run all the twilio related code. The logs just say that the call failed but provide no explanation.

This is the component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Parse from 'parse';
import Axios from 'axios';

var conversationsClient;
var activeConversation;
var previewMedia;

if(!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia && !navigator.mozGetUserMedia)
    alert('WebRTC is not available in your browser.');

function initVideo(){
    getAccessToken().then((response) => {
        const accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager(response.data);
        conversationsClient = new Twilio.Conversations.Client(accessManager);
        conversationsClient.ConstructorOptions = {
              logLevel: 'debug'
        };
        conversationsClient.listen().then(
            clientConnected,
            (error) => {
                log('Unable to create conversation');
                console.error('Unable to create conversation', error);
            }
        )
    });
    document.getElementById('button-preview').onclick = function () {
        if(!previewMedia) {
            previewMedia = new Twilio.Conversations.LocalMedia();
            Twilio.Conversations.getUserMedia().then(
                function (mediaStream) {
                    previewMedia.addStream(mediaStream);
                    previewMedia.attach('#local-media');
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.error('Unable to access local media', error);
                    log('Unable to access Camera and Microphone');
                }
            );
        }
    };
}

function getAccessToken(){
    return Axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/getAccessToken',
        data: {
            username: Parse.User.current().get('username')
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
}

function log(message) {
    document.getElementById('log-content').innerHTML = message;
}

function clientConnected(){
    document.getElementById('invite-controls').style.display = 'block';
    log("Connected to Twilio. Listening for incoming Invites as '" + conversationsClient.identity + "'");

    conversationsClient.on('invite', (invite) => {
        log('Incoming invite from: ' + invite.from);
        invite.accept().then(conversationStarted);
    });


    document.getElementById('button-invite').onclick = function () {
        var inviteTo = document.getElementById('invite-to').value;

        if(activeConversation) {
            activeConversation.invite(inviteTo);
        } else {
            var options = {};
            if (previewMedia) {
                options.localMedia = previewMedia;
            }
            conversationsClient.inviteToConversation(inviteTo, options).then(
                conversationStarted,
                function (error) {
                    log('Unable to create conversation');
                    console.error('Unable to create conversation', error);
                }
            );
        }
    };
}

function conversationStarted(conversation){
    log('In an active Conversation');
    activeConversation = conversation;

    if (!previewMedia)
        conversation.localMedia.attach('#local-media');

    conversation.on('participantConnected', (participant) => {
        log("Participant '" + participant.identity + "' connected");
        participant.media.attach('#remote-media');
    });

    conversation.on('participantDisconnected', (participant) => {
        log("Participant '" + participant.identity + "' disconnected");
    });

    conversation.on('ended', (conversation) => {
        log("Connected to Twilio. Listening for incoming Invites as '" + conversationsClient.identity + "'");
        conversation.localMedia.stop();
        conversation.disconnect();
        activeConversation = null;
    });
}

class VideoContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        let isWebRTCSupported = true;
        if (!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia && !navigator.mozGetUserMedia)
            isWebRTCSupported = false;
        this.state = {
            isWebRTCSupported: isWebRTCSupported
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.state.isWebRTCSupported)
            initVideo();
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="remote-media"></div>
                <div id="controls">
                    <div id="preview">
                        <p className="instructions">Lookin' good!</p>
                        <div id="local-media"></div>
                        <button id="button-preview">Preview My Camera</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="invite-controls">
                        <p className="instructions">Invite another Client</p>
                        <input id="invite-to" type="text" placeholder="Identity to invite" />
                        <button id="button-invite">Send Invite</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="log">
                        <p>&gt;&nbsp;<span id="log-content">Preparing to listen</span>...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you share the code that is different to the quickstart? Please edit the question with the code. Thanks

Comment: @philnash I have edited the code, please check!

Comment: OK, and at which part of the code do you get that error? When you init the video stuff, when you make an invite, when you receive an invite or accept an invite?

Comment: @philnash after the init video is called, the client is connected and i can even see the client's identity. After waiting a couple of minutes, I get that error. And obviously inviting is not working after that!

Comment: Do you find the same issue when you run the quickstart without changing the code at all?

Comment: @philnash quickstart works just fine! This error pops up only when i put this quickstart code inside my react component

Comment: Is there anything more you get from the logs, since you have debug mode set?

Comment: @philnash Setting the loge level to 'debug' didn't help too. Just spits out the same error and nothing else.

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with how React works under the hood, but could it be causing the `conversationsClient` to get garbage collected? Can you try making the `conversationsClient` part of the state?

Comment: @philnash I have initially tried to do it the react way by binding all the variables to state but it didn't work. So I decided to just copy the starter kit as it is into my component to see if it's working. I will do what you suggested and let you know the outcome soon. Thanks!